# Individual user-generated saved responses

Tags: discussion, comments

I am trying to see if anyone is aware of a plugin/utlity where I could keep a list of common responses like

> "Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for..."

or

> "Do you have any code we can build on? This would be a better question ....

If I VTC a question (on Stack Overflow for example) as unclear it won't add a comment. I try my best to add one manually and I end up writing the same text over and over.

Yes, I could keep a text document and save these responses there. I thought I might be able to find something on Stack Apps however I could not find exactly what I was thinking about.

Does anyone have any utilities they use for these sort of scenarios. My primary browser is Chrome if that influences the responses.